# Regex to remove captions with condition not to overlap second match

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string, which I extract from a pdf:

```
This is
Fig. 13: John holding his present and
the flowers
Source: official photographer
a beautiful
Table: a table of some kind
and fully
complete
Table: John holding his present and
Source: official photographer
sentence
```

The text includes figs and tables, most of which have a caption on top and a source on bottom, but some don't. Fundamentally, the text I want to be left with should be:

```
This is
a beautiful
and fully
complete
sentence
```

I have tried the following:

```
s = re.sub(r'(Fig|Table)[\s\S]+?Source:.*\n', '', mystring,flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

But unfortunately it returns:

```
This is
a beautiful
sentence
```

With my limited knowledge of regex I cannot figure out how to put **such a condition**:

It should stop at the first `\n` after `Source`, only if there is no new `fig|table` in between, in which case it should have stopped at the first `\n` from start.

Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: hi Mark, this doesn't answer, here the issue is not just the shortest match, but there is a condition in between which i cannot sort out

Comment: This is non-trivial as you have to "look ahead" to see whether or not a Fig or Table is a one-liner (next token is not "Source:") or a multi-liner (next token is "Source:").  By token I mean one of "Fig", "Table", or "Source:".  Such lookaheads might be possible with advanced regex (been a long while since I tried) but I think you would likely end up with unmaintainable regex code.

Comment: @BareNakedCoder it can be done with a [tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed)

Comment: It could also work with [negated](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) colon: [`^(?:Fig\. \d+|Table):(?:[^:]+^Source)?.+(?:\n|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/I3OflN/3) (depends on how input could look like)

Comment: interesting option, slightly less expensive. thank you for sharing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to match is a `Fig` or `Table` followed by either

1. Characters up to and including a line starting with `Source`, with *no* `Fig` or `Table` in between the original one and `Source`; or
2. Characters up to the end of line

You can achieve #1 above by using a [tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed), which ensures that each character processed until `Source` is found does not precede `Fig` or `Table`. This regex will do what you want:

```
(?:Fig|Table)(?:(?:(?!Fig|Table)[\s\S])+?Source[^\n]*\n|[^\n]*\n)
```

This matches:

- `(?:Fig|Table)` : a word `Fig` or `Table`; and then either
- `(?:(?!Fig|Table)[\s\S])+?` : a minimal number of characters, none of which precede either of the words `Fig` or `Table`
- `Source[^\n]*\n` : The word `Source` followed by some number of characters until newline; or
- `[^\n]*\n` some number of characters until newline

Regex demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gdP0ne/1)

In python:

```py
s = re.sub(r'(?:Fig|Table)(?:(?:(?!Fig|Table)[\s\S])+?Source[^\n]*\n|[^\n]*\n)', '', mystring)
print(s)
```

Output:

```
This is
a beautiful
and fully
complete
sentence
```

Note this does leave newlines (if present in the original string) at the start and end of the string, they can be removed with `strip`.

Comment: wonderful Nick, will study this tempered greedy token usage, as it sounds pretty useful, thank you so much! yes indeed newlines are not an issue so i didn't include them in the original problem, easier to solve with a strip indeed

Comment: @lorenzo Yeah, they are a good way of dealing with problems like this. But they are fairly expensive. Anyway, glad I could help.

Comment: @lorenzo You do not need `[^\n]`, use `.` instead.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew does it matter? [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/21qugS/1) seems to think they cost the same.